# Hide connection strings in vb6 and secure mysql passwords

Tags: mysql, security, vb6, passwords, connection

So,this is how it goes..
Our company have at least 10 servers, And  dozens of systems.My boss wants to secure our mysql passwords. In that case even our programmers wouldn't be able to update,delete or change any data. Reason for this is some of the IT staff is changing  confidential datas, but before we make any legal move against their actions,we decided to secure the servers first, what we did is  get the source code from the programmers and changed all the connection strings like passwords and usernames which is stored in server 5. But the connection string of server 5 is still visible in the source code. My question is, in case we're doing things wrong, is there any other way to make files more secured, than changing and hiding server passwords? if no, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: is there anything to stop them debugging the code and getting all the usernames and passwords?

Comment: If you are sure they did this and you know who it was: suspend them from work immediately. Do not allow them to enter the premises again unless escorted, suspend their logons, impound their laptops. You must be fair and you must demonstrate that you are being fair. Officially this is a precaution while the incidents are being investigated and officially you should not announce anything about guilt/innocence until they've had a chance to hear the accusations and respond. Much later - revise your security systems to try to prevent this happening again.

Comment: I agree with MarkJ, it's sorta subjective as we don't know your company, so his solution is the best.  Do you have a specific programming question and or something regarding related security code?

Comment: Since it appears from your description of the problem that you belive the data is being changed through the program. Have the programmers write a one way encryption function to encrypt and store the user passwords in the database. A user logs in by entering their password, the password is encrypted using the same algorithm, and the encrypted passwords are compared. The user's actual password remains secret.

Comment: ...and make sure you have a current backup.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have a normal problem:
How can you allow an application to access data, without allowing the developers that same access.

- If the developer can access the data without the app, stop here.
- If the developer can read the source and config files, you can't keep the password there.
- If the developer can read the registry (you mentioned VB6), you can't keep the password there.
- If the developer can read the executable (hex editor, or [Sysinternals Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx), etc.), you can't keep the password there.

Essentially, if you must use a username and password that mySQL knows, you have to first forbid developers all access to production, and then have someone else make the config file changes to store the (encrypted) password to the prod servers.
 - Yes, now someone else can get in and muck around
 - Or share that username/password
 - And you've got a similar issue with the key to encrypt the password.

However, it appears that as of commercial MySQL 5.6.10, there is an alternative: use Windows native (Active Directory) authentication.  See [MySQL Reference Manual 6.3.8.6 The Windows Native Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html).
 - You'll have to give developer AD accounts membership in an AD group with rights to development and maybe test
 - You'll have to give real users membership in an AD group with rights to production

No matter what you do, you'll have to put up with a lot of whining from the developers who aren't on administrative leave, and you'll have slower live production debugging by at least a small amount.